# Should meta fields (i.e. last updated date) be part of entity tables?

Tags: relational-database

I have a `hotel` entity, this hotel will have one and only one country.

I have a `country` entity table, it stores all the countries.

I have a mapping table (tho it is 1 - 1) as i felt that country shouldn't be part of a hotel (or should it be?). The question is, should the `last_updated_date` variable be part of the `hotel_country_map` entity?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you move the hotel_country_map columns back into the hotel table, while they do not "right" one can argue that the country is where the hotel is located and is therefore a valid attribute of the hotel.

The last_update_date is valid addition since it tells you when the hotel record was last changed.